# Winforms Textbox with two way DataBinding not working as it should be

Tags: c#, binding, textbox

Winforms has two Textboxes. `textBox2` is binded to a property Unit.
I wish that any changes made to Unit or `textBox2` will automatically update `textBox2` or Unit respectively.  But it does not.
Here are three versions of the code for a Winform.

**Version one** set data binding, hope it will have two ways auto update but does not work

```
public partial class Receiver : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{         

    private int unit=0;
    public int Unit
    {
        get { return unit; }
        set
        {
            if (value != unit)
            {
                unit = value;                                          
            }
        }
    }

    public Receiver()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Unit, "Unit");
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        //textBox1 change makes Unit change, 
        //I wish the change will be displayed in textBox2 automatically
        Unit = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    }        
}
```

**Version two** with event handler , hard code to update `textBox2` with the event handler

but change `textBox2` still will not update Unit automatically

```
public partial class Receiver : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int unit=0;
    public int Unit
    {
        get { return unit; }
        set
        {
            if (value != unit)
            {
                unit = value;                       
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                   PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
                }  
            }
        }
    }

    public Receiver()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.Unit, "Unit", false, 
                                                 DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChanged);

    }    

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Unit = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    }


    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        //this actually is hard coded to update textBox2, binding does no help
        textBox2.Text = Unit.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Version three** why use event handler, we can simply do this way.

```
public partial class Receiver : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    private int unit=0;
    public int Unit
    {
        get { return unit; }
        set
        {
            if (value != unit)
            {
                unit = value;   
                textBox2.text = unit.toString();                          
            }
        }
    }

    public Receiver()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Unit, "Unit");
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Unit = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);           
    }   

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Unit = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);           
    } 
}
```

}

**Version two** and **Version three** have a problem, any changes to `textbox1` will cause update in `textbox2`.  That will cause a lot of CPU cycle. The best way is when the mouse focus leaves `textBox1` then do the update. So how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your code is at line:

```
textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Unit, "Unit");
```

You should replace the data source by the instance that holds that property not the property itself, and here you should also specify the data source update mode set it to `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`. So:

```
textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Unit", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

//test using the second or the third approach:
Unit = 15;//now the textBox2.Text equals to 15 too.

textBox2.Text = 12;//now Unit equals 12 too
```